# File flush needed after process exit?

Tags: python, linux, ext4

I'm writing files from one process using `open` and `write` (i.e. direct kernel calls.) After the write, I simply `close` and exit the application without flushing. Now, the application is started from a Python-Wrapper which immediately after the application exits reads the files. Sometimes however, the Python wrapper reads incorrect data, as if I'm still reading an old version of the file (i.e. the wrapper reads stale data)

I thought that no matter whether the file metadata and contents are written to disk, the user visible contents would be always valid & consistent (i.e. buffers get flushed to memory at least, so subsequent reads get the same content, even though it might not be committed to disk.) What's going on here? Do I need to sync on close in my application; or can I simply issue a `sync` command after running my application from the Python script to guarantee that everything has been written correctly? This is running on ext4.

On the Python side:

```
# Called for lots of files
o = subprocess.check_output (['./App.BitPacker', inputFile]) # Writes indices.bin and dict.bin
indices = open ('indices.bin', 'rb').read ()
dictionary = open ('dict.bin', 'rb').read ()

with open ('output-file', 'wb') as output:
    output.write (dictionary) # Invalid content in output-file ...
    # output-file is a placeholder, one output-file per inputFile or course
```

Comment: Closing the file should flush everything, and exiting the application should close everything. `sync` is irrelevant, because Linux uses a unified buffer cache, so all processes see the same kernel buffers.

Comment: So either you're not writing the data completely, or you're not actually closing the file and exiting the process before you try to read it. You need to post an example that demonstrates the problem, we can't answer this abstract question.

Comment: That's where I'm puzzled as well, as I can guarantee the file is closed and all data is written. It's literally open, write, close, one after the other.

Comment: When the wrapper reads stale data, can you verify that the file has actually been updated?

Comment: The wrapper calls subprocessed.check_output ([...]), and then reads the data. It then writes the data to another location, and what ends up there is not what the process writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had your problem and always found a call to close() to be sufficient.  However, from the man entry on close(2):

> A successful close does not guarantee that the data has been successfully saved to disk, as the kernel defers writes.  It is  not  common for a file system to flush the buffers when the stream is closed.  If you need to be sure that the data is physically stored use fsync(2).  (It will depend on the disk hardware at this point.)

As, at time of writing, you haven't included code for the write processes I can only suggest adding a call to fsync in that process and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to reproduce it any more, it works now with close any. Thanks for clarifying, accepting this answer, as there doesn't seem to be any special handling necessary.